# Infinite series from 1 to infinity of a pi function equation, evaluate for some constants

Tags: calculus

I encountered something similar to this on a quiz and really had no clue how to proceed. Our in-class problem did not have the A+B-C thing but was pretty similar to this

> $$
> \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{\prod_{r=0}^{n-1}{(\pi-r})}{2^nn!}}=\left(\frac{A}{B}\right)^{\pi}-C$$
>   If the equation above holds for coprime integers $A,B,\text{ and }C,$ enter the value of $A+B-C$

https://brilliant.org/problems/crazy-sum-2/

I knew the first step was to use a binomial series, but did not know how to proceed from there. Any suggestions as to how to proceed/solutions?

Comment: Can you typeset your formula using mathjax/latex please?

Comment: The $\pi$ is a snare and a delusion.  Replace it by $x$.  Do you see the binomial series now?

Comment: @saulspatz I replaced it with x, but still, I had to look at the answer key. When I looked at the solution, I just wasn't sure why I had to replace x with 1/2

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of the problem is to recognize the [binomial series.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)
$$(1+x)^{\alpha}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\binom{\alpha}{n}x^n},
$$
where $\alpha$ is a complex number and the (generalized) binomial coefficient $$
\binom{\alpha}{n}=\frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)(\alpha-2)\cdots(\alpha-n+1)}{n!}
$$ 
Rewrite the original equations as $$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\binom{\pi}{n}2^{-n}}=\left(\frac{A}{B}\right)^{\pi}-C
$$
Compare this to the binomial formula.  We see that $x=1/2$ and that we are missing the $n=0$ term, which is $1,$ from the sum; that is the sum is equal to $$(1+1/2)^{\pi}-1\implies 
A=3, B=2, C= 1, A+B-C=4$$

In the future, please take the trouble to typeset your questions in [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).